# How to change the background color of a dynamically created paragraph in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I want the user to be able to .hover() the paragraphs individually with (example: "border: 1px solid #900;") and be able to click it individually also to add/change the background color ("select paragraph") and click again to return default background color ("diselect paragraph").
This paragraphs are dynamically created and im having a hard time to get it since i'm new to Javascript and jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/RzvV5/8/

This is the code Im working with:

```
jQuery

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#push").on({
    click: function(){
        var pr = $('<p class="test">Test</p>');
        var d = $(".Test");
        $(pr).clone().appendTo(d); 
    }
});

$("p").on({
          mouseenter: function(){    
                     $(this).addClass("inside"); 
          },
          mouseleave: function(){                             
                     $(this).removeClass("inside");  
}

});



});
```

---

Html code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="push">Push</a>
<div class="Test"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Css code:

```
.test { color: #000; padding: .5em; border: 1px solid black;} 
.active { background-color: ;}
.inside { background-color: #900; }
```

---

This code is just an example of what im trying to accomplish.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what is happening here is that in your code, you define a function to create a paragraph and then set it's properties. Do note that, you 'define a function'. That alone doesn't make any paragraphs. So when you set event handlers for all paragraphs, it doesn't really matter because the paragraphs you care about don't exist yet.

This is what you could do, change your jQuery part to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#push").on({
        click: function(){
            var pr = $('<p class="test">Test</p>');
            var d = $(".Test");
            var pclone = $(pr).clone();
            pclone.on({
                mouseenter: function(){    
                    $(this).addClass("inside");
                },
                mouseleave: function(){                             
                    $(this).removeClass("inside");  
                }
            });
            pclone.appendTo(d);
        }
    });
});
```

I have edited your JSFiddle a bit further for you to check out the results: http://jsfiddle.net/RzvV5/16/

**Edit**

*P.S* As you've mentioned you're new to jQuery and you seem to be a new user to stackoverflow as well, I commend you for a perfectly asked question. Proper code example, introduction with problem statement and a proof of your own effort, and the best part: a JSFiddle link so that I could check if my answer was right or not. Great going :)

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your JQuery code, you should be able to copy paste it in and give it a try.  It's pretty ugly but I wrote it quickly.  Basically, on click it will make a paragraph with a red background.  When you click it, it turns blue.  If you click it again it turns red.  The code is fairly self explanatory.  Hope that helps!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#push").on({
        click: function(){
            $('<p>Test</p>').css("background-color","red").appendTo('.Test');
        }
    });

$('.Test').on("click", "p", function(){  
    var cur = $(this).css('background-color');
    if(cur=="rgb(255, 0, 0)") {  
        $(this).css("background-color","blue");
    } else {                      
        $(this).css("background-color","red");
    }
    });
});
```

Edit: Replaced use of .live() which is deprecated.

Comment: `live()` is deprecated, use `on()` as of 1.7.1 http://api.jquery.com/live/ `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().`

Comment: Thanks NiftyDude, actually wasn't aware of that.  Behind on the times I guess.  I read up on the changes and modified my original statement to replace live().

Answer (score 0):

You can change the selector that you add the event handler to to the containing element (.Test), and provide the p tag to the call to on:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#push").on({
        click: function(){
            var pr = $('<p class="test">Test</p>');
            var d = $(".Test");
            $(pr).clone().appendTo(d); 
        }
    });

    $(".Test").on( "mouseenter", "p", function(){    
        $(this).addClass("inside"); 
    });
    $(".Test").on( "mouseleave", "p", function(){                            
        $(this).removeClass("inside");  
    });
});
```

.on is similar to .live in that it can effectively attach event handlers to dynamically created elements, however it's far more efficient because it's not attaching the handlers to the root document. Here's an explanation of the various methods of event handling in jQuery 1.7 (along with why and how you should use .on): http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle that I have created :

http://jsfiddle.net/RzvV5/80/

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Anirban